# PHP Send email doesn't work

Tags: php, email

My page contact doesn't send email, but I can't see the problem.
My page says everything works fine, but the email doesn't arrive at the destination.
Can anyone help?

page contact

```
<div id="BoxForm" align="left" style="vertical-align:top;">
    <form action="enviar_contato.php" method="post" id="form">

    <table width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" >
  <tr>
    <td align="right"><label for="name">Nome&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</label></td>
    <td><input type="text" name="name" id="name" /></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td align="right"><label for="email">Email *&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</label></td>
    <td><input type="text" name="email" id="email" /></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td align="right"><label for="subject">Assunto&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</label></td>
    <td><input type="text" name="subject" id="subject" /></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td align="right"><label for="message">Mensagem *&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</label></td>
    <td><textarea name="message" id="message" rows="10" cols="30"></textarea></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td><input type="submit" id="button" name="button" value="Enviar" /></td>
  </tr>
</table>
    <table width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
      <tr>
        <td align="right" valign="middle" height="50px"><a style="  font-size:12px; font-weight:100; margin-top:15px; margin-right:50px;"> Campos com * s&atilde;o obrigat&oacute;rios</a></td>
      </tr>
    </table>

    </form>
```

page enviar_contato.php

```
<?php
    $name     =   $_POST['name']; //pega os dados que foi digitado no ID name.
    $email    =   $_POST['email']; //pega os dados que foi digitado no ID email.
    $subject  =   $_POST['subject']; //pega os dados que foi digitado no ID subject.
    $message  =   $_POST['message']; //pega os dados que foi digitado no ID message.

    $headers  = "From: $email\r\n";
    $headers .= "Reply-To: $email\r\n";

/*abaixo será os dados que serão enviado para o email
cadastrado para receber o formulário.*/

       $corpo = "Formulário enviado\n";
       $corpo .= "Nome: " . $name . "\n";
       $corpo .= "Email: " . $email . "\n";
       $corpo .= "Comentários: " . $message . "\n";

       $email_to = 'luiz@mahy.com.br'; //substitua este email pelo seu email do seu site.

    $status = mail($email_to, $subject, $corpo, $headers); //enviando o email.

    if($status) {
        echo "<script> alert('Formulário enviado com sucesso.'); </script>"; //verifica se foi enviado o email com sucesso.
    }
    else {
        echo "<script> alert('Falha ao enviar o Formulário.'); </script>"; //se houve algum erro de envio.
    }
    echo "<script> window.location.href = 'http://www.mtres.com.br/index.html'; </script>"; //aqui você coloca uma página que será redirecionada após o envio do formulário, dei um exemplo do meu site.

?>
```

anyone see the problem?

Comment: if its only your local machine you need to setup mail

Comment: check your spam folder.  However, It is possible to get a true value for  `$status` as a true value would only mean that the mail was accepted for delivery but does not mean it was sent.  You may be redirecting before the mail is sent.